# SQL: Entity belongs (many-to-one) one of two different entities

Tags: mysql, schema, best-practices

Let's say I have `organization` and `person` and they have a `one-to-many` relationship with `post`.

`post` could only be owned by either an organization or user (person).

What I'm doing right now is making the foreign key nullable and adding a `check constraint` to ensure only one of `organization_id` and `person_id` has a value and the other one is `null`.

Is this considered a valid `SQL` design (best practise)? What if I had more than two entities that could be the owner of a certain post?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to utilize subtypes<sup>1</sup>.  Most often your situation is handled by a `Party` table:

```
CREATE TABLE PartyType
(
  PartyTypeCd  CHAR(1)      NOT NULL /* P - Person, O - Organization */
 ,Name         VARCHAR(50)  NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_PartyType PRIMARY KEY (PartyTypeCd)
 ,CONSTRAINT AK_PartyType UNIQUE (Name)
)

CREATE TABLE Party
(
  PartyId      INT          NOT NULL
 ,PartyTypeCd  CHAR(1)      NOT NULL
 ,Name         VARCHAR(45)  NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT FK_Party_Discriminated_By_PartyType FOREIGN KEY (PartyTypeCd) REFERENCES PartyType (PartyTypeCd)
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_Party PRIMARY KEY (PartyId)
)

CREATE TABLE Person
(
  PersonId  INT          NOT NULL
 ,Bio       VARCHAR(45)  NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT FK_Person_Is_Party FOREIGN KEY (PersonId) REFERENCES Party (PartyId)
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_Person PRIMARY KEY (PersonId)
)

CREATE TABLE Organization
(
  OrganizationId  INT  NOT NULL
  /* Other organization-only properties */
 ,CONSTRAINT FK_Organization_Is_Party FOREIGN KEY (OrganizationId) REFERENCES Party (PartyId)
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_Organization PRIMARY KEY (OrganizationId)
)

CREATE TABLE Post
(
  PostId   INT            NOT NULL
 ,PartyId  INT            NOT NULL
 ,Body     VARCHAR(1000)  NOT NULL
 ,CONSTRAINT FK_Post_Created_By_Party FOREIGN KEY (PartyId) REFERENCES Party (PartyId)
 ,CONSTRAINT PK_Post PRIMARY KEY (PostId)
)
```

You will need to ensure the `PartyTypeCd` matches upon insert into the appropriate subtype table.  In MySQL this must be done via a trigger.

---

<sup>1</sup> You can refer to these SO posts for a more in depth treatment of the topic:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4763141/data-modeling-supertype-subtype
2. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896831/how-to-implement-referential-integrity-in-subtypes